# Tool for generating data driven reports and sending out to external users

Tags: excel, vba, azure, reporting, subscription

My company has been using excel macros to generate data driven reports for years now. The current method has one 'source' excel workbook with pivot tables pointing to either an analysis services model or a sql database and we use a macro to loop through the slicers and generate one report for each slicer option, then save the report to an SFTP for the customer to pick up. These are normally ran on a monthly basis.

This is temperamental and we've started to migrate our data to azure.... i'm looking for some advice on what tools i can use within azure which can do a similar thing?

We do use Power BI, but we don't have the budget to either have a premium licence or give out pro licences to each external company (there are hundreds, maybe thousands).

Any help would be appreciated and apologies if this is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go for Azure logic app that suits your situation and some of the features are mentioned below:

1. No upfront cost
2. visually workflow
3. pay per action billing
4. integration of email is provided

For more information: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/logic-apps/